# RegEx in java to replace a String

Tags: java, regex, string, math, replace

I've been trying to replace this mathematical function `x^2*sqrt(x^3)` to this `pow(x,2)*Math.sqrt(pow(x,3))`

so this is the regex

```
/([0-9a-zA-Z\.\(\)]*)^([0-9a-zA-Z\.\(\)]*)/ pow(\1,\2)
```

it works in ruby, but I can't find a way to do it in java, I tried this method

```
String function=  "x^2*sqrt(x^3)";

  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-z0-9]*)^([a-z0-9]*)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(function);

  String out = function;

  if(m.find())
  {
      System.out.println("GRUPO 0:" + m.group(0));
      System.out.println("GRUPO 1:" + m.group(1));
      out = m.replaceFirst("pow(" + m.group(0) + ", " + m.group(1) + ')');
  }
      String funcformat = out;
      funcformat = funcformat.replaceAll("sqrt\\(([^)]*)\\)", "Math.sqrt($1)"); 

      System.out.println("Return Value :"+ funcion );
      System.out.print("Return Value :"+ funcformat );
```

But still doesn´t work, the output is: `pow(x, )^2*Math.sqrt(x^3)` as I said before it should be `pow(x,2)*Math.sqrt(pow(x,3))`.
Thank you!!

Comment: For general math expression, write a parser to do it. Java regex alone cannot handle nesting brackets. For this specific case, it is possible with regex, but I do not recommend it.

Comment: Agreed that regex is not the way to go. There are many existing parsers out there; you don't have to roll your own.

Comment: Just notice that your input string is weird: `"x^2*sqrt(3x)"` Do you mean `x^3` here?

Comment: @nhahtdh Yeah, already corrected.

Answer (score -1):

As others have commented, regex is not the way to go. You should use a parser. But if you want some quick and dirty:

From [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29):

```
Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. 
Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0)
is equivalent to m.group().
```

So you need to use `m.group(1)` and `m.group(2)`. And escape the caret `^` in your regex.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Replace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String function=  "x^2*sqrt(3x)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-z0-9]*)\\^([0-9]*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(function);
        String out = function;

        if (m.find())   {
            System.out.println("GRUPO 0:" + m.group(1));
            System.out.println("GRUPO 1:" + m.group(2));
            out = m.replaceFirst("pow(" + m.group(1) + ", " + m.group(2) + ')');
        }
        String funcformat = out;
        funcformat = funcformat.replaceAll("sqrt\\(([a-z0-9]*)\\^([0-9]*)]*\\)", "Math.sqrt(pow($1, $2))"); 
        System.out.println("Return Value :"+ function );
        System.out.print("Return Value :"+ funcformat );
    }
}
```

Comment: @nhahtdh You are right. I've fixed the code. I think it works now ... but as I've said, he should use a parser.

Comment: Actually, it is possible to make it work for more test cases. Currently it only works for `x^3*sqrt(x^4)` and fails when you swap around `sqrt(x^4)*x^3`. The idea is to replace all the `name^power`, then replace `sqrt(` with `Math.sqrt(`. It is still not general enough, but at least survive slightly better than the current code.

Comment: @nhahtdh Good catch, I didn't think about that ... definitely regex is not the way.

Comment: this is not generic for all problems like asked query. You have to give a generic solution.